# jQuery Scroll to next/prev section

Tags: jquery, scroll

lots of questions about this - but the solutions I have looked at don't work for my usage.

I need a jQuery function to make the page scroll to the next "section" in my website - but my next / prev buttons are positioned globally above the sections - therefore using approaches like go to next parent don't work, neither does 'find the next 'section' as the hierarchy nesting is not right due to the arrow buttons being external to the sections themselves...

The code must work irrespective of number of sections - and not need hard coded section classes/ids....

Any ideas?

Code example below:

```
<div class="arrows">
<a href="#" class="arrow-up prev-section"></a>
<a href="#" class="arrow-down next-section"></a>
</div>

<section class="panelSection">
... section content here ...
</section>

<section class="panelSection">
... 2nd section content here ...
</section>
```

Comment: How about using $.first() to find the first section, scroll to there and then save the DOM object in a variable so you can use it with $.next() to go to the next section. First quick idea.

Comment: Thanks Adrian - sounds like a good idea... not sure how to save to the DOM though... any code suggestions?

Comment: Check the answer, I cannot post the code in the comment. And again, it's not tested in jsfiddle, so please test it and tell me if it works or at lest helps.

Comment: Thanks - no tis not working at the moment, will see if I can crack it...

Comment: I'm sorry. I will try to fix it if I have time today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
var sections = $('.panelSection');
console.log(sections);
var i =0;
var scrolto = 0;

function next(){

    if(i == 0){
        $('.prev-section').show();
    }
    if(i < sections.length -1){
        i++;
        if(i == sections.length -1){
             $('.next-section').hide();   
        }
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        alert('end reached');
    }
}
function prev(){
    if(i == sections.length -1){
        $('.next-section').show();
    }
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
        if(i == 0){
            $('.prev-section').hide();
        }
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: sections[i].offsetTop
        }, 2000);
    }    
}
$('html').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == '38'){
        prev();    
    }
   if(e.which == '40'){
        next();    
    }
});
$('.next-section').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   next();
});

$('.prev-section').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   prev();
});
```

you store the sections in an array and loop through that array on clicks, then you scroll to the offset top. made the fiddle so it hides the buttons and checks for min-max number of sections, also included up down key arrow support

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yn6maby0/25/

Comment: Thanks - this looks promising yes... Issue though that you can keep firing the functions even when at the top and bottom of the sections... Can you adapt it to prevent being able to click prev when 1st section in view and preventing being able to click next when the last section in view? Otherwise its easy to break this solution

Comment: oh yes, there was a bug i see, edited my fiddle take a look @dubbs

Comment: Last thing... can we add in keyboard up/down control to make the sections change?